# Expert Advisor will not open buy trades and doesn't follow the conditions

Tags: mql4

The EA has no bugs but it doesn't really do what I expected it to do, it should, for example, sell from var_30[i], put a tp at var_2[i] and sl at var_30[i]+(var_30[i]-var_2[i])/2 or buy from var_20[i], put a tp at var_3[i] and sl at var_20[i]+(var_20[i]-var_3[i])/2

I tried to modify it several times but in the end, after using the strategy tester feature the graph always goes to 0, which shouldn't.

Here is the code:

```
#property description "Price Border strategy expert advisor by Razvan"

//--- Inputs
extern double Lots          =1;
extern double MaximumRisk   =2;

extern string TimeFrame = "All tf";
extern int HalfLength = 61;
extern int Price = 0;
extern double ATRMultiplier = 1.6;
extern double ATRMultiplier1 = 3.6;
extern int ATRPeriod = 480;
extern bool Interpolate = TRUE;
extern bool alertsOn = TRUE;
extern bool alertsOnCurrent = FALSE;
extern bool alertsOnHighLow = TRUE;
extern bool alertsMessage = FALSE;
extern bool alertsSound = TRUE;
extern bool alertsEmail = FALSE;
double var_1[];
double var_2[];
double var_3[];
double var_4[];
double var_20[];
double var_30[];
string string_1;
bool bool_1;
bool bool_2;
int var_5;
string string_2 = "nothing";
datetime Gt_176;
string string_3[] = {"M1", "M5", "M15", "M30", "H1", "H4", "D1", "W1", "MN"};
int var_6[] = {1, 5, 15, 30, 60, 240, 1440, 10080, 43200};
int res;

// init function
int init() {
   string str_4[256];
   for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) str_4[i] = CharToStr(i);
int var_7 = StrToInteger(str_4[67] + str_4[111] + str_4[112] + str_4[121] + str_4[32] + str_4[82]+ str_4[105] + str_4[103] + str_4[104] + str_4[116] + str_4[32] +
  str_4[169] + str_4[32] + str_4[75] + str_4[97] + str_4[122] + str_4[97] + str_4[111] + str_4[111] + str_4[32] + str_4[50] + str_4[48] + str_4[49] + str_4[49] + str_4[32]);
   IndicatorBuffers(4);
   HalfLength = MathMax(HalfLength, 1);
   SetIndexBuffer(0, var_1);
   SetIndexDrawBegin(0, HalfLength);
   SetIndexBuffer(1, var_2);
   SetIndexDrawBegin(1, HalfLength);
   SetIndexBuffer(2, var_3);
   SetIndexDrawBegin(2, HalfLength);
   SetIndexBuffer(3, var_4);
   string_1 = WindowExpertName();
   bool_2 = TimeFrame == "returnBars";
   if (bool_2) return (0);
   bool_1 = TimeFrame == "calculateValue";
   if (bool_1) return (0);
   var_5 = func_3(TimeFrame);
   IndicatorShortName(func_0(var_5) + " TMA bands )" + HalfLength + ")");
   return (0);
}
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
// deinit function
int deinit() {
   return (0);
}
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
// start function
int start() {
   int var_7;
   double double_1;
   double double_2;
   double double_3;
   double double_31;
   int var_8;
   int var_9;
   int var_10 = IndicatorCounted();
   if (var_10 < 0) return (-1);
   if (var_10 > 0) var_10--;
   int var_11 = MathMin(Bars - 1, Bars - var_10 + HalfLength);
   if (bool_2) {
      var_1[0] = var_11 + 1;
      return (0);
   }
   if (bool_1 || var_5 == Period()) {
      for (int i = var_11; i >= 0; i--) {
         double_1 = (HalfLength + 1) * iMA(NULL, 0, 1, 0, MODE_SMA, Price, i);
         double_2 = HalfLength + 1;
         var_7 = 1;
         for (int var_12 = HalfLength; var_7 <= HalfLength; var_12--) {
            double_1 += var_12 * iMA(NULL, 0, 1, 0, MODE_SMA, Price, i + var_7);
            double_2 += var_12;
            if (var_7 <= i) {
               double_1 += var_12 * iMA(NULL, 0, 1, 0, MODE_SMA, Price, i - var_7);
               double_2 += var_12;
            }
            var_7++;
         }
         double_3 = iATR(NULL, 0, ATRPeriod, i + 10) * ATRMultiplier;
         double_31 = iATR(NULL, 0, ATRPeriod, i + 10) * ATRMultiplier1;
         var_1[i] = double_1 / double_2;
         var_2[i] = var_1[i] + double_3;
         var_20[i] = var_1[i] + double_31;
         var_30[i] = var_1[i] - double_31;
         var_3[i] = var_1[i] - double_3;
         var_4[i] = 0;
         if (alertsOnHighLow) {
            if (High[i] > var_2[i]) var_4[i] = 1;
            if (Low[i] < var_3[i]) var_4[i] = -1;
         } else {
            if (Close[i] > var_2[i]) var_4[i] = 1;
            if (Close[i] < var_3[i]) var_4[i] = -1;
         }
      }
      if (!(!bool_1)) return (0);
      func_1();
      return (0);
   }
   var_11 = MathMax(var_11, MathMin(Bars - 1, iCustom(NULL, var_5, string_1, "returnBars", 0, 0) * var_5 / Period()));
   for (i = var_11; i >= 0; i--) {
      var_8 = iBarShift(NULL, var_5, Time[i]);
      var_1[i] = iCustom(NULL, var_5, string_1, "calculateTma", HalfLength, Price, ATRMultiplier, ATRPeriod, 0, var_8);
      var_2[i] = iCustom(NULL, var_5, string_1, "calculateTma", HalfLength, Price, ATRMultiplier, ATRPeriod, 1, var_8);
      var_3[i] = iCustom(NULL, var_5, string_1, "calculateTma", HalfLength, Price, ATRMultiplier, ATRPeriod, 2, var_8);
      var_4[i] = iCustom(NULL, var_5, string_1, "calculateTma", HalfLength, Price, ATRMultiplier, ATRPeriod, 3, var_8);
      if (var_5 <= Period() || var_8 == iBarShift(NULL, var_5, Time[i - 1])) continue;
      if (Interpolate) {
         var_9 = iTime(NULL, var_5, var_8);
         for (int var_14 = 1; i + var_14 < Bars && Time[i + var_14] >= var_9; var_14++) {
         }
         for (var_14 = 1; var_12 < var_14; var_12++) {
            var_1[i + var_12] = var_1[i] + (var_1[i + var_14] - var_1[i]) * var_12 / var_14;
            var_2[i + var_12] = var_2[i] + (var_2[i + var_14] - var_2[i]) * var_12 / var_14;
            var_3[i + var_12] = var_3[i] + (var_3[i + var_14] - var_3[i]) * var_12 / var_14;
         }
      }
   }
   func_1();
   return (0);
}
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
// function1
void func_1() {
   int var_10;
   if (alertsOn) {
      if (alertsOnCurrent) var_10 = 0;
      else var_10 = 1;
      var_10 = iBarShift(NULL, 0, iTime(NULL, var_5, var_10));
      if (var_4[var_10] != var_4[var_10 + 1]) {
         if (var_4[var_10] == 1.0) func_4(var_10, "up");
         if (var_4[var_10] == -1.0) func_4(var_10, "down");
      }
   }
}
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
// function4
void func_4(int var_12, string str_5) {
   string str_6;
   if (string_2 != str_5 || Gt_176 != Time[var_12]) {
      string_2 = str_5;
      Gt_176 = Time[var_12];
      str_6 = StringConcatenate(Symbol(), " at ", TimeToStr(TimeLocal(), TIME_SECONDS), " " +         func_0(var_5) + " TMA bands price penetrated ", str_5, " band");
      if (alertsMessage) Alert(str_6);
      if (alertsEmail) SendMail(StringConcatenate(Symbol(), "TMA bands "), str_6);
      if (alertsSound) PlaySound("alert2.wav");
   }
}
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
// function3
int func_3(string str_7) {
   str_7 = func_2(str_7);
   for (int var_7 = ArraySize(var_6) - 1; var_7 >= 0; var_7--)
      if (str_7 == string_3[var_7] || str_7 == "" + var_6[var_7]) return (MathMax(var_6[var_7], Period()));
   return (Period());
}
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
// function0
string func_0(int var_12) {
   for (int i = ArraySize(var_6) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
      if (var_12 == var_6[i]) return (string_3[i]);
   return ("");
}
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
// function2
string func_2(string str_7) {
   int var_13;
   string str_8 = str_7;
   for (int var_11 = StringLen(str_7) - 1; var_11 >= 0; var_11--) {
      var_13 = StringGetChar(str_8, var_11);
      if ((var_13 > '`' && var_13 < '{') || (var_13 > 'ß' && var_13 < 256)) str_8 = StringSetChar(str_8, var_11, var_13 - 32);
      else
         if (var_13 > -33 && var_13 < 0) str_8 = StringSetChar(str_8, var_11, var_13 + 224);
   }
   return (str_8);
}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Calculate open positions                                         |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int CalculateCurrentOrders(string symbol)
  {
   int buys=0,sells=0;
//---
   for(int i=0;i<OrdersTotal();i++)
     {
      if(OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_TRADES)==false) break;
      if(OrderSymbol()==Symbol())
    {
     if(OrderType()==OP_BUY)  buys++;
     if(OrderType()==OP_SELL) sells++;
    }
     }
//--- return orders volume
   if(buys>0) return(buys);
   else       return(-sells);
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Calculate optimal lot size                                       |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
double LotsOptimized()
  {
   double lot=Lots;
   if(lot<0.1) lot=0.1;
   return(lot);
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Check for open order conditions                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void CheckForOpen()
  { int var_10 = IndicatorCounted(); 
   int var_11 = MathMin(Bars - 1, Bars - var_10 + HalfLength);
   for (int i = var_11; i >= 0; i--)
    {if(High[i] > var_30[i] || Close[i] > var_30[i])
     {
      res=OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_SELL,LotsOptimized(),Bid,30,var_30[i]+(var_30[i]-    var_2[i])/2,var_2[i],"",0,Red); //Symbol(),OP_BUY,1,price,3,stoploss,takeprofit,"My order",16384,0,clrGreen
      return;
     }
//--- buy conditions
    else if(Low[i] < var_20[i] || Close[i] < var_20[i])
     {
      res=OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_BUY,LotsOptimized(),Ask,30,var_20[i]+(var_20[i]-var_3[i])/2,var_3[i],"",0,Green);
      return;
     }}
//---
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Check for close order conditions                                 |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void CheckForClose()
  {
   if(Volume[0]>0.1) return;
   for(int i=0;i<OrdersTotal();i++)
     {
      if(OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_TRADES)==false) break;
      if(OrderSymbol()!=Symbol()) continue;
      //--- check order type 
      if(OrderType()==OP_BUY)
        {
         if(High[i] >= var_3[i] || Low[i] <= var_30[i]+(var_30[i]-var_2[i])/2)
           {
            if(!OrderClose(OrderTicket(),OrderLots(),Bid,30,White))
               Print("OrderClose error ",GetLastError());
           }
         break;
        }
      if(OrderType()==OP_SELL)
        {
         if(Low[i] <= var_2[i] || High[i] >= var_20[i]+(var_20[i]-var_3[i])/2)
           {
            if(!OrderClose(OrderTicket(),OrderLots(),Ask,30,White))
               Print("OrderClose error ",GetLastError());
           }
         break;
        }
     }
//---
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| OnTick function                                                  |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
void OnTick()
  {
//--- check for history and trading
   if(Bars<100 || IsTradeAllowed()==false)
      return;
//--- calculate open orders by current symbol
   if(CalculateCurrentOrders(Symbol())==0) CheckForOpen();
   else                                    CheckForClose();
//---
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I'd suggest breaking your code down. Use `Print();` statements to check your code is doing what you expect at various stages. Find a setup manually that you know should open a buy or sell trade and use the strategy tester to test that specific setup. It's not an easy or quick process and you should not expect someone else to do it for you for free. Just because there are no errors when you compile something does not mean it has no bugs. If it is not behaving as expected then it does have bugs.

Comment: Thanks, I will try and check what's causing the EA to not behave properly.